# Warning: JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component _t25

Tags: jsf, navigation

So I created JSF pages from entity classes, and when I open a for example "Create.xhtml" cant add new user, or anything else.

This is warning before I click on "Show all user items" `Warning:   JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component _t25.` and then also: `Warning:   JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component _t50.`

Comment: You're talking about the Netbeans built-in code generator? So the code which you actually didn't write didn't work? Have you already reported it to original authors, thus the Netbeans guys?

Comment: And, asking multiple questions about the same root problem is counterproductive. Just improve the existing question if you don't get the attention you think you need.